# d3js arrowheads not showing

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have an example of force directed graph. And i want to show arrowheads, but no matter what i tried i can't see them.

Here is my javascript

```
    var nodes = {};

    // Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
    links.forEach(function(link) {
        link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {
            name: link.source
        });
        link.target = nodes[link.target] || (nodes[link.target] = {
            name: link.target
        });
    });

    var width = 960,
        height = 500;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
        .links(links)
        .size([width, height])
        .linkDistance(100)
        .charge(-300)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .start();

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
        .data(["arrow"])
        .enter().append("svg:marker")
        .attr("id", "arrow")
        .attr("viewBox","0 0 10 10")
        .attr("refX","20")
        .attr("refY","5")
        .attr("markerUnits","strokeWidth")
        .attr("markerWidth","9")
        .attr("markerHeight","5")
        .attr("orient","auto")
        .append("svg:path")
        .attr("d","M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z")
        .attr("fill", "#f0f0f0");

    var link = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("line")
        .data(force.links())
        .enter().append("svg:line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("marker-mid", "url(#arrow)");

    var node = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll(".node")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 8);

    node.append("text")
        .attr("x", -22)
        .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });

    function tick() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
            .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
            .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
            .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });
        link.attr("marker-mid", "url(#arrow)");

        node.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
    }
```

And [here is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kobayakawa/eFxFC)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [MDN docu on `marker-mid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Attribute/marker-mid):

> The marker-mid defines the arrowhead or polymarker that shall be drawn at **every vertex other than the first and last vertex** of the given  element or basic shape.

So the marker will be inserted at every vertex, but the start and end.

A simple line segment, however, has no other vertices, but its start and end. Thus there are no markers shown in your code.

If you change your `marker-mid` to, e.g., `marker-end`, you will see the arrow heads (although right now, they are not that pretty): [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eFxFC/4/).

Another way, would be to change the `line`-elements to `path` elements and add a additional vertex in the mid. This, however, would require some more sufficient code.

Comment: Its interesting because at first i tried end. And i can't see the arrowheads. Then i changed it to mid because i thought maybe they are under the nodes :D Now i can make them pretty :)