# D3js arrowhead in D3js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've started working with the D3js library to write a tool for visualizing different network structures. Network creation, dynamic interactions such as changing the node size according to degree, searching functionality and animation of nodes' color over time has been implemented, however I'm stuck on drawing the arrow heads on the edges.

After reading the documentation and going through different blocks.org examples, I've come to the conclusion that a svg marker should be the best choice to draw the arrow heads. As I understand from the documentation, arrowheads can be placed on both 'path' and 'line' elements. When I reproduce an example, everything works fine, however when I try to implement the same code into my network visualizer, the arrow heads won't show up. Although clearly something is wrong, I seem to overlook the error.

Basically, I've defined the svg marker as follows:

// define the svg marker for arrow head on edge

```
svg.append('defs').selectAll('marker')
    .data(["arrow"]).append('svg:marker')
    .attr("id", "arrow")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
        .attr('fill', '#ccc')
        .attr('stroke','#ccc');
```

Then I will add it to the links in the network by:

```
var link= svg.append("g")
          .selectAll('line')
          .data(dataset.links)
          .enter()
          .append('svg:line')
          .attr('stroke','black')
          .attr('class','link')
          .attr('marker-end','url(#arrow)');
```

Which will results in the following network: 
https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/c703777036fac93e6ece862a9ac87467

I did have a look at a previous question ([d3js arrowheads not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691077/d3js-arrowheads-not-showing)), however this did not result in solving the problem.
Maybe somebody has an idea to get the arrowheads working?

Update: after the comment by ccprog i have updated the bl.ocks 
https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d1165b950dc50f9ddfcf3c344c05591e

Comment: in your bl.ocks, you have a `<line>` element instead of a `<path>` for your arrow, as correctly in your code above, and the referenced ids do not match the `#marker` id.

Comment: Thanks! This was a very bad mistake which I should have seen by myself.